# Replace all elements in a list from list of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of lists where 1 of the lists ifs full of nans.

```
l_of_l=[[1,2,3],[nan,nan,nan],[3,4,5]]
```

I would like to replace the list of the l_of_l with the nans for zeros:

The desired output is

```
l_of_l=[[1,2,3],[0,0,0],[3,4,5]]
```

This is my code:

```
     for list1 in l_of_l:
         if all(np.isnan(list1)) == True:
              list1 = [0] * len(list1)
```

However i am not sure on how could I assign the result again to the l_of_l without needing to generate a new list of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

[[0 if np.isnan(j) else j for j in i] for i in l_of_l]
# [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0], [3, 4, 5]]
```

If you want to avoid importing `numpy`, though the data suggests that you should be using it, you could actually do the same with:

```
[[0 if j!=j else j for j in i] for i in l_of_l]
# [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0], [3, 4, 5]]
```

This works as by definition `NaNs` are never equal to themselves

---

Or directly build a `numpy` array and use `nan_to_num`:

```
np.nan_to_num(np.array(l_of_l))

array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [3., 4., 5.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.nan_to_num`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html#numpy-nan-to-num) since you are using `numpy` anyway

```
import numpy as np
l_of_l= np.array([[1, 2, 3],[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [3, 4, 5]])
print(np.nan_to_num(l_of_l))
```

prints

```
[[1. 2. 3.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [3. 4. 5.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the list of lists by index, this way you don't neet to generate a new list, you just update it on index:

```
for i, lst in enumerate(l_of_l):
    if all(np.isnan(lst)) == True:
        l_of_l[i] = [0] * len(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

With single `np.num_to_nan` call:

```
import numpy as np

l_of_l = np.array([[1,2,3],[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],[3,4,5]])
np.nan_to_num(l_of_l, copy=False)
print(l_of_l)
```

The output:

```
[1. 2. 3.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [3. 4. 5.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
import numpy as np

l_of_l=[[1,2,3],[np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],[3,4,5]]
final_l_of_l = []

for listt in l_of_l:
  my_list = []
  my_list = [0 if np.isnan(n) else n for n in listt]
  final_l_of_l.append(my_list)


final_l_of_l
```

OutPut :

```
[[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0], [3, 4, 5]]
```