# replace nan in list of list

Tags: python, list, nan

I am trying to replace nan's from a list. I have tried these solutions.

[Replace all elements in a list from list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768717/replace-all-elements-in-a-list-from-list-of-lists)

However, I get the following error: TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting

```
list_of_lists=[[1,2,3],['nan','nan','nan'],[3,4,5]]
```

I'd like to replace nan with a string like "replaced" and expect:

```
list_of_lists=[[1,2,3],['replaced','replaced','replaced'],[3,4,5]]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried list comprehension?

Comment: show your actual input list, nan is obviously not a string here, i'm guessing np.nan

Comment: my nan is a float nan, i didn't recognize that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are representing `nan` as string, which is not a correct representation,
you can either use `float('nan')` or `math.nan`
Anyways, taking this thing into account, you can do something like this:

```py
>> from math import nan, isnan
>> list_of_lists=[[1,2,3],[nan, nan, nan],[3,4,5]]
>> [['replaced' if isnan(i) else i for i in j ] for j in list_of_lists]
```

**Output**:

```py
[[1, 2, 3], ['replaced', 'replaced', 'replaced'], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple way of doig that.

```
new_list = [y.replace('nan','replace') if y == 'nan' else y for x in list_of_lists for y in x  ]
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 'replace', 'replace', 'replace', 3, 4, 5]
```